# Start a countdown timer with react-natiev

Tags: react-native

I want to have a countdown component for my project. I tried by setting setInterval, but I have a requirement to pause and continue the timer. So How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your requirement exactly? If it's just about pausing timer on the screen wit a click, etc.., it can be all implemented with JavaScript. However if it's about the app going to background or foreground, setInterval won't work there.

Comment: I want a timer to run from 10.00 to 0.00. I should be able to stop the timer by clicking on a button. And then resume it. This is my requirenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a jsfiddle with a simple demonstration of how it can be done: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/258601/. Written using React but the principle is exactly the same with React Native.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      counter: 10,
    };

    this.interval = null;

    this.cleanUp = this.cleanUp.bind(this);
    this.decreaseCounter = this.decreaseCounter.bind(this);
    this.startCounter = this.startCounter.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    cleanUp();
  }

  cleanUp() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  decreaseCounter() {
    if (this.state.counter === 0) {
        return this.cleanUp();
    }
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter - 1});
  }

  startCounter() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.decreaseCounter, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.startCounter}>Start</button>
        Counter {this.state.counter}
        <button onClick={this.cleanUp}>Stop</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a component using this. Now I want to pass the counter from parent screen to this one. 

In the parent screen, 
<Timer counter={10} />

If I do this, then the state of the timer cant be changed. Could you please give a tip on this?

Comment: @Shashika I added a parent component, maybe that can help you: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/259442/.